# C# MultiThreading Loop entire DataTable while limiting threads to 4

Tags: c#, multithreading

This may be a tricky question to ask, but what I have is a DataTable that contains 1000 rows.  Foreach of these rows I want to process on a new thread.  However I want to limit the threads to 4 threads.  So basically I'm constently keeping 4 threads running until the whole datatable has been processed.

currently I have this;

```
  foreach (DataRow dtRow in urlTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => MasterCrawlerClass.MasterCrawlBegin(dtRow));
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
```

I know this is backwards but i'm not sure how to achieve what I'm looking for.  I thought of a very complicated while loop but maybe that's not the best way?  Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: Your code example starts 4 thread per row, i do not believe that this is intensionally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest solution would be in case you have 4 CPU cores - Parallel LINQ +Degree of parallelism == 4 would give you one threads per CPU core, otherwise you have manually distribute records between threads/tasks, see both solutions below:

## PLINQ solution:

```
urlTable.Rows.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
             .Select(....)
```

Manual distribution:

You can distribute items by worker threads manually using simple trick:
 N-thread would pick up each `N+4` item from the input list, for instance:

- First thread: Each`0+4` == 0, 3, 7...
- Second: Each`1+4` == 1, 4, 8...
- Third: Each`2+4` == ...

## Task Parallel Library solution:

```
private void ProcessItems(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
     // TODO: ..
}

var items = new List<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
                                       .Select(i => i + "_ITEM"));
var items1 = items.Where((item, index) => (index + 0) % 4 == 0);
var items2 = items.Where((item, index) => (index + 1) % 4 == 0);
var items3 = items.Where((item, index) => (index + 2) % 4 == 0);
var items4 = items.Where((item, index) => (index + 3) % 4 == 0);

var tasks = new Task[]
    {
       factory.StartNew(() => ProcessItems((items1))),
       factory.StartNew(() => ProcessItems((items2))),
       factory.StartNew(() => ProcessItems((items3))),
       factory.StartNew(() => ProcessItems((items4)))
    };

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

MSDN:

- [WithDegreeOfParallelism()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx):
- [Introduction to PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but i just really want to limit it

Comment: So just run 4 threads and no more, or what you are trying to limit?

Comment: The problem is I need to limit it to 4 threads, while being able to iterate the entire datatable, each row in the datatable needs to operate on it's on thread, which means at any given time i should be processing 4 rows

Comment: Well, 4 threads runs slower than one thread on one core, that is if they do not wait for data to process.  I recommend that you let PLINQ or Threading.ThreadPool handle the number of threads and concentrate on the tasks that needs to be processed.